# How to integrate logstash in nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm working on node application and my main goal is to maintain the logs (error, info) of the backend part in logstash so that I could do some analysis of which API is breaking and why. I'm new to logstash and I read some basics of the logstash and elastic stacks. I want to achieve the following -

- Integrate logstash to maintain the logs.
- Read the logs to analysis the breaking changes.

I don't want to integrate the elastic search and kibana. I tried winston-logstash but it's not working and this library source code is not maintainable either. If anyone knows how to implement the above thing in nodejs application, Please let me know.

Comment: Why not write your logs to a file and use filebeat to send it to logstash?

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks for your response but I don't want to use the extra file to store the logs on the server-side. Is there any direct approach to send the logs directly to the logstash?

Comment: I don't know about node, but to send logs directly from a application to logstash you can use the tcp/udp input and send your logs as you were sending it to a syslog server, you can also use the http input and send your events using it.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks again. Do you have any reference link for this?

Answer (score 0):

If your nodejs app runs as a docker container, you can use the [gelf](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gelf/) logging driver and then just log to console/stdout in nodejs and it will get routed to logstash.

Keep in mind Logstash is really just for transformation/enrichment/filtering/etc. you still probably want to output the log events (from Logstash) to an underlying logging solution e.g. elasticsearch.